# How can I implement an atomic get or set&get key in redis using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, redis, redis-py

I have a redis server and I want to implement an atomic (or pseudo atomic) method that will do the following (**NOTICE:** I have a system that has multiple sessions to the redis server) :

1. If some key **K** exists get the value for it
2. Otherwise, call [SETNX function](http://redis.io/commands/setnx) with a random value that is generated by some function **F**(that generates [salts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)))
3. Ask redis for the value of key **K** that was just generated by the current session (or by another session "simultaneously" - a short moment before the current session generated it)

The reasons that I don't want to pre-generate (before checking if the value exists) a value with function **F**, and use it if the key doesn't exist are :

1. I don't want to call **F** with no justification (it might cause an intensive CPU behaviour(
2. I want to avoid the next problematic situation :
   T1 : Session 1 generated a random value **VAL1**
   T2 : Session 1 asked if key **K** exists and got "False"
   T3 : Session 2 generated a random value **VAL2**
   T4 : Session 2 asked if key **K** exists and got "False"
   T5 : Session 2 calls [SETNX](http://redis.io/commands/setnx) with the value **VAL2** and uses **VAL2** from now on
   T6 : Session 1 calls [SETNX](http://redis.io/commands/setnx) with the value **VAL1** and uses **VAL1** from now on where the actual value of key **K** is **VAL2**

A python pseudo-code that I created is :

```
    import redis
    r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
    ''' gets the value of key K if exists (r.get(K) if r.exists(K)), 
    otherwise gets the value of key K if calling SETNX function returned TRUE 
    (else r.get(K) if r.setnx(K,F())), meaning this the sent value is really the value,
    otherwise, get the value of key K, that was generated by another session a         
    short moment ago (else r.get(K))
    The last one is redundant and I can write "**r.setnx(K,F()) or True**" to get the 
    latest value instead, but the syntax requires an "else" clause at the end '''
    r.get(K) if r.exists(K) else r.get(K) if r.setnx(K,F()) else r.get(K)
```

Is there another solution?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use [WATCH](http://redis.io/commands/WATCH) for this. Here's a modified example with [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py):

```
def atomic_get_set(some_key):
    with r.pipeline() as pipe:
        try:
            # put a WATCH on the key that holds our sequence value
            pipe.watch(some_key)
            # after WATCHing, the pipeline is put into immediate execution
            # mode until we tell it to start buffering commands again.
            # this allows us to get the current value of our sequence
            if pipe.exists(some_key):
                return pipe.get(some_key)
            # now we can put the pipeline back into buffered mode with MULTI
            pipe.multi()
            pipe.set(some_key, F())
            pipe.get(some_key)
            # and finally, execute the pipeline (the set and get commands)
            return pipe.execute()[-1]
            # if a WatchError wasn't raised during execution, everything
            # we just did happened atomically.
        except WatchError:
            # another client must have changed some_key between
            # the time we started WATCHing it and the pipeline's execution.
            # Let's just get the value they changed it to.
            return pipe.get(some_key)
```

Comment: Will it create a transaction every time we call ***atomic_get_set*** method? isn't it an overhead? My system characteristics are that I won't have too much keys/entries, and once a key has a value, it won't change, so maybe a if r.exists(some_key): return r.get(some_key) at the beginning of the function will avoid constantly creating new transactions

Comment: We're running `if pipe.exists(some_key): return pipe.get(some_key)` in immediate execution mode, so no overhead there. Really, on the Redis side, everything goes so fast the bottlenecks are almost always going to be on the network side, and this code will do everything you want with at most 2 networks back-and-forths.

If you need to go even faster, you could write F() in lua and run the whole thing as a single Lua call, but unless you're running this function many times a second, the savings from that probably aren't worth it. Don't prematurely optimize unless you realize you have to.

Comment: there is a problem with ***return pipe.get(some_key)*** clause, it doesn't return the actual string value, but a StrictPipeline object..

Comment: Apparently, the StrictPipeline's execute method returns an array of the results that were executed in the pipeline so instead of lines "return pipe.get(some_key)" + "pipe.execute()", I think it should "return pipe.get(some_key).execute()[-1]" to get the result of the last command

Comment: The developer respond :
A pipeline instance can operate in two modes. The default mode is to buffer all commands until pipeline.execute() is called. The execute method returns a list of results from the buffered commands.
Optionally, you can use the pipeline.watch(key1, key2, ...) method to put the pipeline in immediate execution mode. When watching keys, pipeline commands will return results immediately until pipeline.multi() is called.The multi method will return the pipeline to the default buffered execution mode.This is what Eli suggests with his answer.It seems you forgot the watch method

Comment: What developer? Are you experiencing problems with the answer, or does it work?

Comment: The developer of redis-py. And yes, I had a problem that I wrote above, and handled it, but I wanted to update you for enriching your knowledge too (as a thank you:)), and for updating your answer.

Comment: But I have `pipe.watch(some_key)` in my answer before the `pipe.get(...)`. What are you asking I change? If there is something wrong with the answer, I'd love to know what it is for enriching my knowledge. You can also suggest an edit on the answer itself if it's easier for you to explain yourself that way.

Comment: you need to change the "return pipe.get(some_key)" that is before the "pipe.execute()" to "pipe.get(some_key)" and then "return pipe.execute()[-1]"

Comment: Looking at this, I am really confused by the `return pipe.get(some_key)` *before* `pipe.execute()`. That doesn't make any sense to me in terms of normal Python execution.

Comment: @erewok that code is incorrect and was an accident on my part. Tal Barda above has the correction to the oversight, and I've edited the answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out! I haven't looked at the answer in years and forgot I meant to change this.

Comment: Aha. Thanks for coming back and fixing it and for the clarification.